# Setting up non-BB email account on a Blackberry programmatically

Tags: blackberry, email

I have a BlackBerry 9630 running OS v5.0.0.624.  I can add my Gmail account (or any existing non-BB email account) by going to SETUP | EMAIL SETTINGS.

I am trying to find some way of either a) setting up an alternative account programmatically from within my BB application, or b) using `Invoke` to start up the email settings application and allowing the user to set up the alternative account there.

Is either A or B possible?  I'd prefer option A, but B is an acceptable alternative.